# How to style last tag img css?

Tags: css

Hi all I have problem with wordpress content . the code is hide and when I inspect the element the code looks like:

```
<img src="vassasa.jpg">
<img src="qqassasa.jpg">
<img src="zzffassasa.jpg">
<img src="assasa.jpg">
<img src="qqfhassasa.jpg">
```

So I want to css style last tag img

and my code:

```
img:last-child{
    margin-bottom:100px;
}
```

but not work, Help me please.

Comment: what is it's parent? you need to specify the parent elem before the img:last-child selector.

Comment: trying adding display:inline-block or display: block as well.

Comment: I try ur code but it margin all img u can see my problam at http://westecmedia.com/?page_id=758

Comment: and click read more to see problam

Comment: For the record, you *don't* need to specify the parent when using :last-child. The difference between :last-child and :last-of-type is :last-child will only look at the "last child" of the parent, while :last-of-type will look at the last time the selector appears in the parent. for example in  `<div><p>..</p><p>..</p><img/></div>`, `p:last-of-type` will match the second `<p>`, `p:last-child` will match nothing, and `img:last-child` and `img:last-of-type` and `div > :last-child` will match the `<img>`. In your case, there must be some sibling following `<img src="qqfhassasa.jpg">`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should define :last-child only within the parent element but if that's not the case you may use :last-of-type pseudo class:

```
img:last-of-type{
  margin-bottom:100px;
}
```

Comment: I try ur code but it margin all img u can see my problam at http://westecmedia.com/?page_id=758

Comment: Use: `#dess-events-single a:last-of-type img{}` to css for img or `#dess-events-single a:last-of-type` to css a tag.

Comment: ohh please edit ur answer to #dess-events-single a:last-of-type img{}  and than I am accept

Comment: I think I should not edit my answer as it would be irrelevant to the question for further readers.

Answer (score 2):

`img:last-child` selects the last img of the body.
You need to specify the parent element of those img tags. Like this:

```
#dess-events-single p a:last-child img {
  /* style here */
}
```

Comment: I try ur code but it margin all img u can see my problam at http://westecmedia.com/?page_id=758

Comment: @dreamster The `a` tag is not the last-child as per OP's markup in the website.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal OP or website? which do you mean? Check his website code; and I have mentioned this in the edit history.

Comment: I meant to be a:last-child won't work because it is not last-child in his website.

Comment: see the `p` before `a`?

Comment: Ooops, I didn't see or you edited.. but then no need to use :last-child, you may use just a tag but even the solution won't work for the op. The only option is to use :last-of-type or define a class to the last and apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src"vassasa.jpg">
```

Replace with:

```
<img src="vassasa.jpg">  //missing = sign
```

Comment: that could be a typo when he wrote in SO